# My Android code works in onCreate but not as standalone function.Why?

Tags: android

I am trying to use the HP print plug-in for Android 4.4.2 to print a screen capture -- named Small Image. So, I have some code:

```
        PrintHelper imagePrinter = new PrintHelper(getBaseContext());
        imagePrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
        imagePrinter.setColorMode(PrintHelper.COLOR_MODE_COLOR);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.golf_pic_sm); 
        imagePrinter.printBitmap("Small Image", bitmap);
```

And, I inserted this code into the `onCreate()` function of the `Activity` in which I will use the code as a standalone function. The HP plug-in dialog box came up and appeared when I inserted the code into the `onCreate()` function (see below.)

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.display_new);

        //Printer dialog box code
        PrintHelper imagePrinter = new PrintHelper(getBaseContext());
        imagePrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
        imagePrinter.setColorMode(PrintHelper.COLOR_MODE_COLOR);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.golf_pic_sm); 
        imagePrinter.printBitmap("Small Golf Image", bitmap);

        View captureButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View editButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View printButton = findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        printButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View saveButton = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    }
```

However, when I remove the printer code and create an Android function in the same `Activity`, and connect the `setOnClickListener` to the screenPrint function, nothing happens. (the screenPrint function code is below.)

```
    public void printCard()
    {
        PrintHelper imagePrinter = new PrintHelper(getBaseContext());
        imagePrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
        imagePrinter.setColorMode(PrintHelper.COLOR_MODE_COLOR);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.golf_pic_sm); 
        imagePrinter.printBitmap("Small Golf Image", bitmap);
    }

public void onClick(View v) { 
    switch(v.getId()) { 
        case R.id.button1: 
            Intent capture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(capture, CAMERA_REQUEST); break; 
        case R.id.button2:
            break; 
        case R.id.button3: 
            Intent j = new Intent(this, About_TGS.class); 
            startActivity(j); 
            break; 
        case R.id.button4: 
            finish(); 
        case R.id.Button01: 
            printCard(); 
            break; 
    } 
return; 
}
```

Comment: small type -- imagePrinter.printBitmap("Small Image", bitmap) has a older typo "Small Golf Image"... oops...

Comment: have you called printCard() in onCreate ?

Comment: How did you "connect the setOnClickListener to the screenPrint function"?

Comment: No, I have not called the printCard() from onCreate. And, I used a switch statement to connect the screenPrint function [ printCard() ] to the button ID. see below...

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
     Intent capture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(capture, CAMERA_REQUEST);
     break; 
    case R.id.button2:
     break;
    case R.id.button3:
     Intent j = new Intent(this, About_TGS.class);
     startActivity(j);
     break;
    case R.id.button4:
     finish();
    case R.id.Button01:
     printCard();
     break;
   }
   return;
  }

Comment: You should add that to your post so it's easier to read. Also, is it crashing or have you set a beakpoint or log in the `printCard()` function to see if it gets called at all?

Comment: There shouldn't be a `return` in your `onClick()`

Comment: YES the return at the end of the switch statement and another Print Spooler not started solved my problem.... thank you codeMagic!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to use `getBaseContext()`?  Activities themselves are contexts, so if you need a context, you should just be able to use `this` for context while inside your activity class.

Alternatively, you could use `getApplicationContext()` (a method in the `Activity` class).

The documentation for `getBaseContext()`:

> returns the base context as set by the constructor or setBaseContext

This (and the results of your code not working outside of the `onCreate()` method) indicates that the setting of the base context is dependent on the activity's life cycle events.  Using the activity or application context should solve your problem.